# Problems with valgrind

Tags: c

I am trying to do a function that cleans a given code from comments. The code works fine but valgrind doesn't like it. Input contains the code that should be cleaned and I'm trying to save the cleaned code to newcode. I have tried different values with malloc but valgrind doesn't seem to like it. My code looks like this:

```
char *remove_comments(char *input)
{
    int a=0;
    char *newcode=malloc((strlen(input))*sizeof(char));
    int c=0;
    while (a<strlen(input)){
        if((*(input+a)=='/') && (*(input+a+1) =='/')){
            while(*(input+a)!='\n'){
                a++;
            }
            a++;
        }
        if(*(input+a)=='/' && *(input+a+1)=='*'){
            int b=1;
            while(b!=0){
                a++;
                if(*(input+a)=='*' && *(input+a+1)=='/'){
                    b--;
                }
            }
            a++;
            a++;
        }
        *(newcode+c)=*(input+a);
        a++;
        c++;
    }
    free(input);
    return newcode;
}
```

and the valgrind output looks like this:

```
==30337== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==30337==    at 0x402E50: mycompare_new (checkhelp.c:86)
==30337==    by 0x401F23: test_remove_comments (test_source.c:81)
==30337==    by 0x406FD2: srunner_run (in /tmp/user/ee67882dc0b6fb0b4d921c48de81577a5d87cccdc65e0a1580d6726d197a5e87/c-kurssi/Module_3/08_polisher/test/test)
==30337==    by 0x402512: tmc_run_tests (tmc-check.c:134)
==30337==    by 0x4021A7: main (test_source.c:206)
==30337==  Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation
==30337==    at 0x4C2DB8F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==30337==    by 0x402FF1: remove_comments (source.c.nomain.c:18)
==30337==    by 0x401EBD: test_remove_comments (test_source.c:74)
==30337==    by 0x406FD2: srunner_run (in /tmp/user/ee67882dc0b6fb0b4d921c48de81577a5d87cccdc65e0a1580d6726d197a5e87/c-kurssi/Module_3/08_polisher/test/test)
==30337==    by 0x402512: tmc_run_tests (tmc-check.c:134)
==30337==    by 0x4021A7: main (test_source.c:206)
==30337== 
==30337== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==30337==    at 0x402E50: mycompare_new (checkhelp.c:86)
==30337==    by 0x4020BA: test_remove_comments (test_source.c:109)
==30337==    by 0x406FD2: srunner_run (in /tmp/user/ee67882dc0b6fb0b4d921c48de81577a5d87cccdc65e0a1580d6726d197a5e87/c-kurssi/Module_3/08_polisher/test/test)
==30337==    by 0x402512: tmc_run_tests (tmc-check.c:134)
==30337==    by 0x4021A7: main (test_source.c:206)
==30337==  Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation
==30337==    at 0x4C2DB8F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==30337==    by 0x402FF1: remove_comments (source.c.nomain.c:18)
==30337==    by 0x402045: test_remove_comments (test_source.c:102)
==30337==    by 0x406FD2: srunner_run (in /tmp/user/ee67882dc0b6fb0b4d921c48de81577a5d87cccdc65e0a1580d6726d197a5e87/c-kurssi/Module_3/08_polisher/test/test)
==30337==    by 0x402512: tmc_run_tests (tmc-check.c:134)
==30337==    by 0x4021A7: main (test_source.c:206)
==30337==
```

Comment: I think you're missing the null-termination char (+1) to your `malloc`

Comment: Valgrind complains on your tests, what does mycompare_new does?

Comment: You might want to name a, b, and c something more descriptive like `input_pos`, `output_pos` (they can be done away with by incrementing the pointers themselves, just keep a copy of `newcode` to return). I think `b` can be replaced with a [`while(1)` and `break`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_break_statement.htm). You can increment twice with `a+=2`. It's a bad idea to free other people's memory, unless it's a destructor, don't free `input`. Let the caller decide when they're done with it.

Comment: Good point on freeing input; what happens if input is a string literal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are bunch of issues with this code.

1. You're working with C strings, which are sequences of characters with a terminal NUL (\0). But when you allocate space for newcode, you only allocate the length of input and don't leave room for the NUL. You should allocate `strlen(input)+1`.
2. The loop compares `a` with `strlen(input)` each time through the loop, meaning you're recalculating the length of input for every character you see. Calculate it once and save it in a variable, or just loop `while (!input[a])` which will cause it to stop looping when it hits the NUL at the end of input.
3. The `*(input+a)` syntax is unnecessary; use `input[a]`.
4. If the last two bytes of the string are "//", or if the the code includes a "//" not followed by '\n', then the inner while loop will loop through memory until it encounters a '\n'. Always check for NUL when looping over strings and terminate the loop if you encounter one. Same thing with the inner loop for the "/* ... */" case.
5. The code will incorrectly recognize "/*/" as a comment.
6. If the input contains two comments in a row, e.g., "/*X*//*Y*/" then the code will not recognize the second comment. It will skip the first comment but then add the initial '/' of the second comment to newcode and continue.
7. You aren't adding a NUL to the end of newcode before returning it.

I imagine you're getting the valgrind error in the test because you're doing strcmp with the returned string, and since it isn't NUL-terminated, strcmp is wandering off into uninitialized heap memory.